# Using ZIPFoundation without URL

Tags: swift, macos, zip, zipfoundation

In my MacOS app I am downloading an encrypted `.zip` file to the disk. I decrypt this file and keep the decrypted version in memory in the `Data` type. For security reasons the decrypted `.zip` will only be kept in memory.

I can successfully use [ZIPFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation)'s Closure based reading to extract the file contents in memory, but only by using an URL pointing to the (decrypted) `.zip` on disk:

`guard let archive = Archive(url: url!, accessMode: .read) else { return }`

Is there any way I can use the library with data only existing in memory? If not, can you point me towards a library that can handle this?
I have already tried [DataCompression](https://github.com/mw99/DataCompression), but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a (non-merged) Pull Request open that adds in-memory processing of ZIP archives to ZIP Foundation.
Sadly there are still some unresolved issues with in-memory writing of archives. The reading part is using `fmemopen` and should already work.
While the PR is not finished yet, you can have a look here: https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation/pull/78/

Comment: Thank you! I only need read access. I will see if I can make the `fmemopen` solution work.